# Retrieve information using Barcode EAN128

Tags: barcode, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a requirement to make some data retrieval using barcode EAN128.

In form there must be 2 controls; the first is `itemId` and 2nd is `nameAlias`, both from `inventTable`. My issue is that when user will scan the `itemId` it must retrieve the `nameAlias` too in the second control. So for that I made two display methods in my table which I'm using as datasource.

I dragged those methods into my form's design.

This is the first control's code:

```
public display BarcodeString myB()
{
  Barcode barcode;
  InventTable inv;
  ;
  barcode = Barcode::construct(BarcodeType::EAN128);
  barcode.string(true, inv.ItemId);
  barcode.encode();

  return barcode.barcodeStr();
}
```

This is code for the second control, which must retrieve the nameAlias

```
Public display ItemNameAlias qty()
{
  return InventTable::find(this.myB()).NameAlias;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: In the future, please don't screenshot your code. Copy and paste it here instead; this will make it easier for us to work with it and help with your issue.

Comment: Ok, I will foresee your remark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed up barcode printing and barcode data entry.

When printing you need to process your item id into a string suitable for the barcode font.
This is what the `barcodeStr` method do.

On entry you need a scanner. The scanner gives you your item id, as if you have entered it your self. Thus no further processing of the barcode is needed. The scanner takes care of that.

Provided you have an `ItemId` field in your table, create a display method for that table:

```
display ItemNameAlias nameAlias()
{
    return InventTable::find(this.ItemId).NameAlias;
}
```

Do not copy the method to the form, but reference it from the form [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa595058.aspx).
In your form you will have two controls, `ItemId` bound to your field and `nameAlias` refering to your display method.